# Edit Total line in Oracle report 1

Tags: oracle

The data structure:

`sql-> desc t1`

```
- List item
   p_code number,
   acc_date date ,
   debit number,
   credit number
```

Data inside my table:

`sql-> select * from t1;`

```
| p_code | acc_date | debit | credit |
| 001    | 01-01-15 | 100   | 25     |
| 001    | 02-01-15 | 0     | 125    |   
| 001    | 03-01-15 | 415   | 85     |
```

I would like to do something like this:

```
select * from t1  
where acc_date between :fromdate and :todate 
union all
    select p_code, (sum(nvl(debit,0))- sum(nvl(credit,0))) open_balance  
    from t1
    where acc_date < :fromdate
;
```

But, I can't figure out what are my mistakes.

Answer (score 3):

Type and number of columns in `union` must be the same -

```
select p_code, acc_date, debit, credit, null as open_balance
  from t1
 where acc_date between :fromdate and :todate
union all
select p_code, null as acc_date, null as debit, null as credit,
       (sum(nvl(debit, 0)) - sum(nvl(credit, 0))) open_balance
  from t1
 where acc_date < :fromdate
```

Comment: PLEASE HELP ...report plus every time open_balance +  in debit_acc - credit_acc =

Comment: Can you detail the problem?